# Calculating the difference between an entry and the next entry in an ordered data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have a `data.frame` containing information from a website log. Among other columns the `data.frame` contains the cookie ID, the timestamp and the URL. Now I want to compute the time spent on each page, assuming that a page is viewed until another page is loaded by the same cookie ID. This is why the `data.frame` is ordered by cookie ID and timestamp using:

```
data = data[with(data, order(cookie_id, timestamp)), ]
```

Here is how I calculate the time spent on each page using a `for` loop:

```
data$calc_time_spent = NA
for (i in 1:(nrow(data)-1)) {
  if (!is.na(data$cookie_id[i]) & !is.na(data$cookie_id[i+1]) & data$cookie_id[i] == data$cookie_id[i+1]) {
    data$calc_time_spent[i] = data$timestamp[i+1]-data$timestamp[i]
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this is very slow, so I need a more sophisticated solution, maybe using the apply-function?

-

Here are some example data:

```
cookie_id = c("5", "5", "8", "8", "8")
timestamp = as.POSIXlt(c("2005-4-19 7:01:33", "2005-4-19 7:01:35", "2005-4-19 7:01:10", "2005-4-19 7:01:23", "2005-4-19 7:01:27"))
data = data.frame(timestamp, cookie_id)
```

Which look like this:

```
    timestamp   cookie_id
1   2005-04-19 07:01:33 5
2   2005-04-19 07:01:35 5
3   2005-04-19 07:01:10 8
4   2005-04-19 07:01:23 8
5   2005-04-19 07:01:27 8
```

After the operation the data should have a third column:

```
    timestamp   cookie_id   calc_time_spent
1   2005-04-19 07:01:33 5   2
2   2005-04-19 07:01:35 5   NA
3   2005-04-19 07:01:10 8   13
4   2005-04-19 07:01:23 8   4
5   2005-04-19 07:01:27 8   NA
```

Comment: Something like `ave(data$timestamp, data$cookie_id, FUN=diff)`? Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have now provided a reproducible example..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want to take the difference between vectors. Consider the following (although I could be more helpful if you provide reproducible data)

```
data$calc_time_spent[2:length(data$calc_time_spent)] - 
  data$calc_time_spent[1:(length(data$calc_time_spent) - 1)]
```

If you want to do this within each Cookie ID, consider using the "plyr" package or possibly data.table. It should be straightforward to include these commands inside a "ddply" wrapper or a "data.table" command, using

```
### Data Table Approach (faster)
library(data.table)
data[, time.spent := calc_time_spent[2:.N] - calc_time_spent[1:(.N - 1)], 
     by = cookie_id]

### Plyr approach (slower)
library(plyr)
ddply(data, .(cookie_id), summarize,
      time.spent = calc_time_spent[2:length(calc_time_spent)] - 
                   calc_time_spent[1:(length(calc_time_spent) - 1)])
```

Note the .N is a built in constant within Data.Table which is a length 1 vector reporting the number of observations within each "cookie_id" group.

Of course, you could also use a built in function, such as "diff", if you wanted.

Comment: I get the following error when trying the table solution:
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , `:=`(time.spent, calc_time_spent[2:.N] -  : 
  unused argument (by = "cookie_id")

Btw. I have provided an example now.

Comment: I think it would be safer to use diff in case `.N =1`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. It a hack. I'm still interested in knowing how to apply a function the works on two rows at a time, and also have a conditional statement saying that "if SOMETHING, then use NA".

```
data$timestamp_next = c(data$timestamp[2:length(data$timestamp)], data$timestamp[1])
data$time_on_page = data$timestamp_next - data$timestamp
data$cookie_id_int = as.integer(data$cookie_id)
data$cookie_id_int_next = c(data$cookie_id_int[2:length(data$cookie_id_int)], data$cookie_id_int[1])
data$cookie_id_same_as_next = data$cookie_id_int == data$cookie_id_int_next
data$time_on_page[data$cookie_id_same_as_next == FALSE | is.na(data$cookie_id_same_as_next)] = NA
data$cookie_id_int = NULL
data$cookie_id_int_next = NULL
data$cookie_id_same_as_next = NULL
```